# Who was the last Brahma-Vadini as per scriptures before the current Kaliyuga?

Tags: brahmavadini

I am interested in knowing if there was some chronological order associated with them and if it's possible to find out the last one.

Comment: Draupadi was said to be a Brahmavadini. We we find any mention of such most probably she is the last one before age of kali.